# Hibernate - Which inheritance strategy should I use for a class which isn't abstract, but sub-classes may not need tables

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, jpa, hibernate-annotations

I have a simple inheritance relationship in my project, and I'd like to have the super class be abstract.  Some of the inheriting classes will require extra database information, but others will not.  I'm not sure which inheritance strategy to use.

I can't seem to find a straight answer as to weather a super-class can have an abstract class with the JOINED strategy.

I suspect the number of sub-classes won't become too large, and none of them should have *much* extra data, so perhaps a SINGLE_TABLE would suffice.

I really don't want to have extra tables for no reason, so TABLE_PER_CLASS is inappropriate.

I'd appreciate any guidance.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If subclasses don't need tables, I would almost always just use a single table approach to inheritance. If, for some reason, one of the subclasses which does need a table has some absurd amount of extra fields (say 10+), the extra data might indicate that you need to create separate tables for some subclasses and flat tables for others.

How this would be specifically mapped in hibernate, I'm not sure, but I think that's a sensible way to model it.

Comment: Thanks!  That's what I was thinking, I'm still not sure if a JOINED strategy might be better though.

Comment: @Stefan  I am really happy to see your opinion. On a project at work inheritance was used. There is a `Master` entity and about 17 subclass entities because, while most of the data fields are similar, each subclass might have one or two (sometimes a few more) unique fields. At first this seemed right, until I ran into problems like allowing a user to change the subclass type or seeing 17 joins in a query because there are 17 tables. So you think a single table with null values where appropriate would be better? I am still an ORM newbie, but I was thinking that in the back of my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Too late to answer this question, but might help if others have a similar scenario.

Use a SingleTable strategy and if you thing one of the subclasses has more number of fields and need a separate table, then mark that subclass as a SecondaryTable using @SecondaryTable annotation and use PrimaryKeyJoin(there is an annotation for this) to join with superclass on pk column. Also, all the fields in the subclass should be mapped to secondaryTable explicitly using 'table' attribute in @column annotation.